# trying to understand Spring's @RunWith, @ContextConfiguration; and ANT

Tags: java, spring, ant, junit, annotations

I'm using Spring's test annotations for the first time, and trying to understand how they fit togther. The doc says to use @RunWith to specify test runner and @ContextConfiguration to specify context config xml file. I want to run these tests through ant's JUnit task.

I read that @RunWith is a JUnit annotation, so ant's JUnit task should not have any problem processing it. But @ContextConfiguration is a Spring annotation, so how does JUnit process it? Or does Spring convert the test class into a subclass of JUnit TestCase and somehow specify the test runner? How do they actually work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` you tell JUnit to use an other Runner. In this case the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` Runner. The Spring Runner then handles the `@ContextConfiguration` Annotation.

So it works, no matter if you start the test from Eclipse, an ohter IDE, command line, Maven or Ant.